# Detect if a Facebook user is using the "use facebook as" feature using the Javascript sdk

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

We ran into an edge case where someone using our facebook app opened a notification from a fb page they administer in a new tab. In the new tab they used the "use facebook as" mode as their page and when they came back to the app(different tab), app_requests started timing out and a refresh showed the "you are using facebook as.. switch back" prompt.

Does anyone know if there's a way to detect if a user has started using facebook with the "use as" feature as a different user? I would like to detect the change and then handle the change ex: window.refresh() so facebook will show the prompt.

I've played around with using the FB JS SDK's FB.getLoginStatus but I haven't been able to detect any changes in the response object when I replicate the scenario above.